# how to write .htaccess and protect sites files and folder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

i developed a website in laravel but problem is if someone know the name of files he can directly access that files of website which i don't want

```
JobScholar
   app 
    Exceptions 
    Http     
    Mail 
    Models   
    Permission.php       
    Providers   -    
    Role.php     
    User.php 
.env 
  etc etc
```

application is working fine but what i want if user type

```
http://localhost:8080/JobScholar/app/
or
http://localhost:8080/JobScholar/User.php/
```

he should rediret to home controller or see an error message

my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        Options -Indexes
        ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost:8080/JobScholar/index
        Options +FollowSymLinks
    </IfModule>


    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /JobScholar/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

## Don't listing directory
#Options -Indexes
#
## Follow symbolic links
#
#
## Default handler
#DirectoryIndex index.php
```

i don't want the user to access any of the file or `directory` the only directory and files he can see are only those whose `routes` are defines

Comment: If anything except the `public/`dir of your app is accessible, your virtual host is not configured correctly. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#configuration

Answer (score 0):

Laravel basic flow is that ALL the requests go through `index.php` file in `public` folder. So you have to make sure your server points all the request to that folder so `index.php` can serve and take care of the rest.

Quick fix is to create vHost file(assuming you're not on shared host).
Here's a sample:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site.com
    ServerAlias site.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site_name/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/site_name/public>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

On apache server it will go in:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

Then enable the site `a2ensite site_name.conf`

Finally point your site to server IP in `/etc/hosts` like so: `127.0.0.45   site.com`

Also be sure to enable mod rewrite using `a2enmod rewrite` so `.htaccess` provided by Laravel can make required rewrites to the URL.

Finally restart apache: `service apache2 restart`